# Mount encrypted HFS in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, mount, hfs

I try to mount an encrypted HFS+ partition in Ubuntu.

An [older post](https://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write) described quite good how to do it, but lacks the information how to use encrypted partitions.

What I found so far is:

```
  # install required packages
  sudo apt-get install hfsprogs hfsutils hfsplus loop-aes-utils
  # try to mount it
  mount -t hfsplus -o encryption=aes-256 /dev/xyz /mount/xyz
```

But once I run this I get the following error:

```
  Error: Password must be at least 20 characters.
```

So I tried to type it in twice, but that results in this:

```
  ioctl: LOOP_SET_STATUS: Invalid argument, requested cipher or key (256 bits) not supported by kernel
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference, but have you tried `aes256` instead of `aes-256`?

Comment: yes - same result for both - even just using "aes" gives the same result

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You **can't mount** an HFS+ partition encrypted in OS X using `mount`'s option `encryption=aes`. The reason is that encrypted HFS+ partitions and volumes use a **proprietary** format.

Neither [Cryptoloop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptoloop) nor [Loop-AES](http://loop-aes.sourceforge.net/loop-AES.README), which are the underlying decryption methods used by `mount` and `encryption`, understand that format.

This is what I found out:

Cryptoloop can mount partitions or disk images encrypted as a single AES block (this is called single-key mode, see http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Cryptoloop-HOWTO/#cryptoloop-introduction):

```
  /dev/sdXX                                                        
  disk image                                                       /dev/loopX
+-----------+                                                    +-------------+
|           |                                                    |             |
|           |                                                    |             |
|           |                                                    | unencrypted |
| AES block | -AES passwd->AES key->decrypt I/O to loop device-> |  partition  |
|           |                                                    |             |
|           |                                                    |             |
|           |                                                    |             |
+-----------+                                                    +-------------+
```

AES-Loop can mount single-key (like above) and multi-key encrypted partitions or disk images:

```
  /dev/sdXX                                                        
  disk image                                                         /dev/loopX
+------------+                                                    +-------------+
|AES block #1|                                                    |             |
+------------+                                                    |             |
|AES block #2|                                                    | unencrypted |
+------------+ -AES passwd->AES key(s)->decrypt I/O to loop dev-> |  partition  |
|AES block #3|                                                    |             |
+------------+                                                    |             |
|    ...     |                                                    |             |
+------------+                                                    +-------------+
```

On the other hand, an encrypted  HFS+ partition:

- includes a **header** (you can dump it with `xxd`)
- uses **several** keys in an undocumented way (see http://events.ccc.de/congress/2006/Fahrplan/attachments/1244-23C3VileFault.pdf)
- beginning with OS X 10.7 "Lion", it is wrapped in a CoreStorage Logical Volume Group (see `man diskutil` or https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html)
- uses [AES-XTS](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38E/nist-sp-800-38E.pdf):

  ```
     $ diskutil coreStorage list
     (...)
     +-> Logical Volume Family D1C4665F-EAC8-4DAB-B392-634842A59559
         ----------------------------------------------------------
         Encryption Status:       Unlocked
         Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
         (...)
  ```

  which doesn't seem to be supported by Cryptoloop nor Loop-AES.

Cryptoloop's successor, `dm-crypt`, can't read encrypted HFS+ either.

**But before all hope is gone:**

- A group of cryptographic experts have created `vfdecrypt` (included in
  Ubuntu package `dmg2img`, tar.gz is here:
  http://code.google.com/p/iphone-elite/downloads/list), which decrypts
  encrypted FileVault disk images (it won't work with device files).

  This tool looks very promising but didn't work with any of
  several encrypted disk images I created with `Disk Utility` on OS X
  10.8.2 "Mountain Lion". Other people (http://bre.klaki.net/blog/2011/08/17/) seem to have had success
  with old encrypted images.
- Other experts work on project `libfvde`
  (https://code.google.com/p/libfvde), which includes command
  `fvdemount` for reading FileVault encrypted system volumes. The
  limiting factor here is "system volume". It doesn't support
  partitions on removable media. If you're curious, the description is
  here:
  https://code.google.com/p/libfvde/wiki/Mounting#Mouting_the_system_volume.
  The source code can be downloaded here:
  https://code.google.com/p/libfvde/downloads/list.

**As for the error messages you encountered:**

First error:

```
Error: Password must be at least 20 characters.
```

Surprisingly, `mount` enforces long passwords not only for encryption but also for **decryption**, although you may not have control over the partition to decrypt. You can only get around this nuisance by downloading and editing the source and recompiling. (Other distributions, like SuSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES), don't have this restriction.)

Second error:

```
ioctl: LOOP_SET_STATUS: Invalid argument, requested cipher or key (256 bits) not supported by kernel
```

You need to load the Cryptoloop kernel module:

```
$ sudo modprobe cryptoloop
```

because although you installed package `loop-aes-utils` you **are not** using Loop-AES.

Loop-AES uses several modified user space tools (`mount`, `umount`, `losetup`, `swapon` and `swapoff`, provided by `loop-aes-utils`) and a modified `loop.ko` kernel module. Recent Ubuntu versions compile an unmodified `loop` module into the kernel:

```
    $ cd /usr/src/linux-source-3.2.0/linux-source-3.2.0/drivers/block/
    $ diff -q /tmp/loop.c-3.x.patched loop.c
    Files /tmp/loop.c-3.x.patched and loop.c differ
```

so Loop-AES can't be used on Ubuntu out of the box. You need to patch and recompile the kernel as explained here: http://loop-aes.sourceforge.net/loop-AES.README. That's why `mount` still needs Cryptoloop.

If you still get a similar error message after loading `cryptoloop.ko` the encryption type may be not recognized. For example, my Ubuntu 12.04 didn't recognize `aes-128`, but `aes`. SLES only recognizes `aes-128`.

Comment: +1 for the in-depth information and detail provided in the answer.

Comment: This is a simply phenomenal answer. Exceptionally informative, detailed, and apparently extremely well researched. Thanks for sharing jaume, thanks a lot.

Comment: Just wanted to note that I've just tried this on OSX 10.10.3 with success. I also found that the process of decrypting the drive wouldn't make any progress when I was doing much with the computer. However, with the laptop on wall power and the drive plugged in, I left the lid closed (full sleep) and it finished the decryption while it slept in PowerNap.

Answer (score 18):

Actually, there is Java application [hfsexplorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/) that is able to open encrypted `.dmg` files and creates decrypted `.dmg` images which can be mounted in Linux.

I was able to create encrypted `.dmg` files in OS X 10.9.5 and then explore the image from a virtual machine running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. Both AES-128 and AES-256 encryption worked for my test cases.

This is how I created the `.dmg` image:

```
$ hdiutil create -size 10m -layout NONE -fs HFS+ -encryption AES-256 -volname "Vault" vault.dmg
```

From the virtual machine running Ubuntu I was able to open the image:

```
$ ./hfsexplorer-0/bin/hfsexplorer.sh /tmp/vault.dmg
```

It prompts for a password and then shows the content of the image. There is an option (Tools -> create disk image) which creates an decrypted disk image which can then be mounted with the hfs tools from linux.

```
$ mount vault_decrypted.dmg /mnt/hfs/
```

Even HFS+ Journaled file systems worked. The only limitation is that the write support to HFS+J file systems is disabled by default in Linux.

This demonstrates that the encryption of `.dmg` is understood by `hfsexplorer` and could possibly be implemented in the `mount` command. With creating an unencrypted `.dmg` it is possible to mount the image in Linux ultimately.

`vfdecrypt` did not work for me either.