# Write Access to OSX HDD From Ubuntu

Tags: macos, ubuntu, hard-drive

I'm on Ubuntu MATE trying to get write access to an OSX hard drive to backup a buddy's data on his MBP that bit the dust when the battery exploded in the computer.  I've seen the thread over here:

[How to mount a HFS partition in Ubuntu as Read/Write?](https://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write)

That said to use this to remount:

sudo mount -t hfsplus -o remount,force,rw /dev/sdx# /mount/point

My question, is the sdx# where you tell Linux which HDD to remount?  If so how do you find that number?  I'm a real noobie when it comes to Linux and I'm trying to pick it up as I go, I just don't want to mess his stuff up so figured I'd better ask first.

- Note: The HDD is still good.  I can see all his files and open them in sudo, but can't copy/paste which is why I need write access to back it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a the Ubuntu terminal you can type 'sudo fdisk -l' to list drives and partitions.

Comment: And that drive is what goes on the sdx# portion?  Does it take the place of the whole sdx# string or just the '#' character?

Comment: Replace sdx with the partition label. So if it's sda1 then use /dev/sda1. If it's sdb1 then use /dev/sdb1

Comment: Sounds good, thank you! I'm assuming that this will give me enough capability to recover his files off the HFS+ journaled partition?

Comment: Have you installed hfsprogs?

Comment: Not currently, I just found the link I posted today and plan on doing this this evening when I get home.  But when I install that and do the remount, I should be good correct?

Comment: Yeah you should be good to go. Let me know if you run into any errors.

Comment: Will do...and this is a fairly safe method correct? Shouldn't corrupt any files or anything?

Comment: It shouldn't do

Comment: I did:
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o remount,force,rw /dev/sda2 /meida/Macintosh HD
And I'm still getting permission errors.  Do you see anything wrong with this?

Comment: can you be sure that /dev/sda2 is the correct device? Otherwise the only thing I can think of is for you to get access to an OS X device and disable journaling.

Comment: /dev/sda2 is the 232.1G Apple HFS/HFS+  type.  Then I have the /dev/sda3 that's the 619.9M Apple boot.  How do you disable journaling?  Will that make it so the files can get corrupt?  He has some important stuff he needs off

Comment: After doing some research it seems that Linux doesn't like journaled partitions and so can't read or write. The only way to disable journaling is to  connect the device to a mac and either use disk utility or run `diskutil disableJournal /Volumes/TheVolumeName` in the terminal. The files shouldn't be corrupted.

Comment: but it has to be done from a mac?  so i've managed to get things to the /root/desktop but can't transfer them to my user desktop to upload them.  any ideas there?  I'm getting close I think...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44024/discussion-between-wgdvs-and-superuser-do).

Comment: From my understanding it does have to be done with a mac. If you're having trouble moving files i suggest you use terminal and use `sudo mv /root/desktop/file /user/desktop`.