# MacBook Pro running Ubuntu 16.04 and OS X Yosemite

Tags: macbook

I need help getting write access to my Mac HD from Ubuntu. I can view and open the files in my Mac HD but I cannot write to the Mac HD. The options for "New folder" or "paste" are just grayed out when I'm in the Mac HD.

I have already gone into OS X and disabled journaling but no luck.

**A full history;**

When I first installed Ubuntu, I couldn't get ANY access to my Mac HD although I could see it on my "Files" application. I looked up some online solutions and tried this:

1. `sudo apt-get install hfsprogs` (install HFS programs into Linux)
2. `sudo mount -o force /dev/sdX /your/mount/point` (not sure what this is)
3. `sudo mount -o remount,rw,force /mount/point` (remount)

...this didn't help.

**what worked for me was:**

1. `sudo useradd -d /home/tempuser -m -s /bin/bash -G admin tempuser` (create a temp user on Linux)
2. `sudo passwd tempuser` (setup password for new user)

Reboot and log in as `tempuser`. Then, open up the Terminal and type in the following commands:

3. `sudo usermod --uid 502 myusername` (match my Ubuntu UID with that of OS X)
4. `sudo chown -R 502:myusername /home/myusername` (no idea what this does)

....but after all this, although I could now access the Mac HD, it remains read only access until now.

Comment: idk whether this is a dupe, but - http://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write

Answer (score 0):

This is weird but I think I will now answer my own question!...for those who might have the same problem in future.

After messing around, I noticed that my mount options in "Disks" were set to "`ro`". Even my basic computer knowledge could recognise that meant read only, so(after a bit more research), I deleted the "`ro`" and bobs your uncle, I now have full access to my Mac HD.

All that was needed was to remove "`ro`" from "`nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,ro,x-udisks-auth`" in the mount options of my Mac partition. I think this is what you might have been suggesting Arduino.

Thanks to ever so much to all of you that responded.