# How can I mount an HFS (not HFS+) filesystem read/write in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, hfs

I have some HFS disk images (pre-Mac OS 8; not HFS+) which I'd like to be able to mount read/write in Linux. However, this command:

```
sudo mount -t hfs -o force,rw sys7.dsk mnt
```

gives me:

```
mount: /media/daryxfox/woah/daryx/macemu/mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I can mount images read only just fine like this:

```
sudo mount -t hfs sys7.dsk mnt
```

I've also read on here that for hfs+ you need to disable journaling, but hfs doesn't even have journaling so that can't be the issue. If the 'native' hfs driver in Linux simply won't write to HFS, is there another option (I have a vague recollection of a user-mode program that would mount NTFS filesystems r/w before Linux was able to natively)?

Thanks.

Comment: I am just at the same point. I found [hfsutils](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hfsutils) which seem to use different set of commands. With a bit more search I could find xhfs which gives you a frontend to the hfsutils commands. However I couldn't manage to mount my drive with this set either. If you have any update, please let me know!

Comment: You may find help here: https://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write Cheers!